# how to stop or terminate while loop in java whenever we want

Tags: java, exception, while-loop

I am getting Unreachable code compilation error when I am using true in while loop
my code:

```
LoginService();

while(true)
{
   //some stuff
}

LogoutService(); //getting compilation error Unreachable code
```

How to handle the situation ?

Comment: Well, have a condition that breaks out of the infinite while loop.

Comment: The expression at the start of while loop is evaluated after each repeat of the while loop, and if the expression evaluates to `true`, the while loop will go for another round. Since `true` always evaluates to `true`, you're essentially saying "never stop"

Answer (score 0):

Your getting that error because you have an infinite loop due to your true condition in the while loop. You should reevaluate the reason for your while loop and provide an appropriate exit out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error because the compiler has detected an infinite loop.  To fix this, try this version, which uses a boolean variable to control loop execution:

```
LoginService();
boolean flag = true;

while (flag) {
    //some stuff

    if (condition) {
        flag = false;
    }
}

LogoutService();
```

This fixes your compiler error and also makes your logic explicit for when the loop should continue executing.

Answer (score 0):

As much as possible (I would suggest never) use a `while(true)` !

Just put an exit condition in your while :

```
boolean exitLoop = false;
while(!exitLoop){ /*do stuff*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while(true)` never ends and so `LogoutService()` will never be called! Have some logic that breaks the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`while(true){...}` without any `break` inside means that the code after the `while` statement could never been reached. It is a compilation error.

> [14.21. Unreachable Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21)
>
> It is a compile-time error if a statement cannot be executed because
>   it is unreachable.
>
> This section is devoted to a precise explanation of the word
>   "reachable." The idea is that there must be some possible execution
>   path from the beginning of the constructor, method, instance
>   initializer, or static initializer that contains the statement to the
>   statement itself. The analysis takes into account the structure of
>   statements. Except for the special treatment of while, do, and for
>   statements whose condition expression has the constant value true, the
>   values of expressions are not taken into account in the flow analysis.

So to solve your issue, make the last statement reachable. 
For example :

```
LoginService();

while(true)
{
    // ...
    if (someCondition){
        break;
    }
}

LogoutService();
```

Comment: There is no possibility to write if condition. The loop has to run continously (24 hours) and we want to stop the loop whenever we want. Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: @Think Smart. You would have precised it in the question. It matters a lot. "Stop whenever" is board. If you want to stop it from the running application, define the processing in a thread and give a way to stop it. Whatever edit your question if you want to get a relevant answer.